# How to use Spotify with a proxy for subscribers

Tags: windows, proxy, spotify

I have a subsribe Spotify account, and I would like to use in my job, but my proxy has blocked all streamming data, I can use it by a VPN in a VMWare machine but it consume more resources, I Would like to know if is any way to use Spotify with my host computer but with a specific proxy just for Spotify.

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick OT hint -- you could also make offline playlists with the songs that you want. That way you don't eat up too much traffic on the VPN.

Comment: I forgot to say I am a unnlimited usert Not premium..

Comment: If you can make it work in a VM that runs on your host, then it will work just as well on your host.

Comment: yes It works with a Vmware but I have to use a VPN.

Comment: Finally I Use my university proxy(you should check If you have one) because all the proxy I found on internet are blocked by spotify, and You should try to start Your spotify and then click in setup  your proxy.